# How to synchronize asynchronous methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an image processing javascript. Through a file input with an id 'image_input' user can choose to upload an unlimited number of images. When an user uploads images, my jQuery code below catches them and calls my image processing code for each image.

```
$('#image_input').change(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    image_count = input[0].files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < image_count; i++) {
        Uploader.processImage(input[0].files[i]);
    }
});
```

The process image function creates a new HTML img element and loads the user uploaded image into it. The script waits until the image is loaded and then it converts it into a suitable format and size. Finally, the image is saved into an array: Uploader.images.

```
Uploader.processImage = function(image) {
    var image_element = document.createElement('img');
    var image_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
    image_element.onload = function() {
        image_data = convert(this);
        Uploader.images.push(dataUriToBlob(image_data));
    }
    image_element.src = image_url;
}
```

**I want the images to be stored in the array in the order they were uploaded.** The problem is that the onload function is asynchronous, which means that I cannot control in which order the images are saved. For instance, I choose to upload 3 images. Image 1 and image 2 are each 10MB of size but image 3 is only 300 KB. Therefore, conversion of the image 3 is finished first and the final order of the images in the array is 3, 1, 2 (or 3, 2, 1).

How can I synchronize the execution of processImage so that the next image is processed only when the conversion of the previous one is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at locks in javascript:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/locks

Comment: Thank you very much. I have rewritten my code using locks and it works like a charm. I had some trouble installing the Locks API. I don't use any other 3rd party javascript library, so I just included their javascript file index.js in my HTML page and commented out calls on object 'exports' which my browser didn't recognize.

Answer (score 1):

[Locks are great](https://github.com/Wizcorp/locks), as @Esse answered.  I also recommend checking out [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) (This is what I usually use) and [Promises.js](https://github.com/stackp/promisejs).

[This is a great article](http://phucnguyen.info/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-async-meteor/) about Async in the Meteor framework.  It gives a great overview of how Fibers work though.

Comment: Thank you. I will check out fibres but I don't think it gets any easier than locks. It took me less than 1 minute to implement them into my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Promises to solve a problem like this. I like the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library that implements the [Promises/A+](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) standard.

[More on Promises on HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Made a small image loading script using the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [Qimage](https://github.com/gre/qimage) libraries showing the principles of Promises in a situation similar to the one in the question:

```
var arrOfImgUrls = [url1, url2, url3];    

//Loads images from an array of URLs
function loadImages(urls) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        //Qimage loads and image from an URL and returns a Promise.
        //If the Promise is fullfilled we get an <img> node
        //as the resolve value.
        //
        //We push the Promises on to an array
        promises.push(Qimage(urls[i]))
    }
    //Return the array of Promises
    return promises;
}

//Q.all() returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array
//containing the fulfillment value of each promise, or is rejected 
//with the same rejection reason as the first promise to be rejected.
Q.all(loadImages(arrOfImgUrls))
//If all Promises are fullfilled the the resolve callback is called
.then(function (imgs) {
    //We get an array of <img> nodes in the same order as the
    //'arrOfImgUrls'-array
    console.log(imgs);
},
//Else the reject callback is called with the same rejection 
//reason as the first promise to be rejected.
function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```